# useEffect Hook not firing function enclosed inside it

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, redux-thunk, use-effect

I have the following component in my reactjs application:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';    
import MovieList from '../components/MovieList';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { getMoviesDiscover} from '../actions';


const Wrapper = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    width:100%;
    flex-direction: column;
`;


const Discover = ({
    geral,
    movies
}) => {

    const query = 'popular';

    useEffect( () => {
        getMoviesDiscover( query );
    } , [] );

    if( movies.loading ) {
        return (
            <div>
                Movies are loading..
            </div>
        )
    }

    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <Helmet>
                <title>Danm Gurl</title>
            </Helmet>
            <MovieList 
                movies={ movies }    
            />
            <MovieList 
                movies={ movies }    
            />
        </Wrapper>
    )

}

const mapStateToProps = ({ geral, movies }) => {
    return { geral, movies };
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    { getMoviesDiscover }
)(Discover);
```

As you can see i am using the React Hook useEffect like so ::-

```
useEffect( () => {
            getMoviesDiscover( query );
} , [] );
```

The problem is if i add a console.log inside the `useEffect` , i see the console.log in console. But the function `getMoviesDiscover` is never executed. The getMoviesDiscover function is in an  external file and looks like below:

```
export const getMoviesDiscover = ( name , page ) => async ( dispatch , getState ) => {
    console.log('OK !')
    dispatch({ type : 'FETCH_MOVIES_LOADING' })
    const res = await tmdbAPI.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${name}?api_key=<MY_API_KEY>` , {
        params: {
            page
        }
    });
    await dispatch({
        type: 'FETCH_MOVIES_DISCOVER',
        payload: res.data
    });
    dispatch({ type : 'FETCH_MOVIES_FINISHED' })
}
```

Why is my useEffect Hook not invoking the function ?

Comment: `getMoviesDiscover` looks to be a curried function, you're just passing a `name` parameter to it and it is returning the actual async function which you haven't called yet. Perhaps you still need to invoke a call, something like `getMoviesDiscover('popular')()`.

Comment: @DrewReese is right. I think the main issue here is that you are not binding your `getMoviesDiscover` action the right way. Try adding it to your component's props. If that won't help, try explicitly creating a `mapDispatchToProps` function with `bindActionCreators` used on your `getMoviesDiscover` action and pass it to `connect`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So right now what's happening is that the imported (thunk)function `getMoviesDiscover` from '../actions' is being called directly rather that the one that's passed into  `mapDispatchToProps`. So you will need to destructure this function in your props, e.g.
`({
    geral,
    movies,
getMoviesDiscover
}) => {`

You may also need to do `getMoviesDiscover as myNewFuncName` to avoid shadow variable errors